# using 2 formtextfield throws exception '<optimized out>': is not true

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

I'm using 2 FormTextField in a form, both take numbers , first for landline and second for mobile number,when I use only one field the apps works fine but when I add the second field I get this exception when the page loads :

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ══════

The following assertion was thrown during paint():

'dart:ui/text.dart': Failed assertion: line 1372: '': is not true.

this is the code :

```
                       Flexible(
                          flex: 1,
                          fit: FlexFit.loose,
                          child:  Form_Text_Field_Number(
                            tf_label: 'Landline # ',
                            fieldController: landlineFieldController,
                            icon: Icons.phone,
                          ),

                        ),
                        Flexible(
                          flex: 1,
                          fit: FlexFit.loose,
                          child: Form_Text_Field_Number(
                            tf_label: 'Mobile #',
                            fieldController: mobileFieldController,
                            icon: Icons.phone_android,
                          ),
                        ),
```

the design of both fields is the same based on FormTextField..only field name differ.

I tried some suggestions like placing the text field in a Container ...but non solved the issue.

why this happen only when adding the second field , what could be the reason ?
and how to solve.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm encountering the same issue.

Comment: @Rafie.. Hi.. Not yet.. I guess the solution should comes from flutter people.. Obviously its a API bug.

Comment: I have no idea how to report a bug to flutter :)

Comment: I've updated flutter to the latest and the issue is gone. Are you on the latest version?

Comment: Will try the latest..